# Redux-Logger - 'reducer' is not defined

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-logger

Title.

I'm trying to learn how to use [Redux-Logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger) (dont know whether LogRocket is required, considering it hasnt been updated in years to state its needed but I digress )

According to the usage, the basic implementation is

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';

// Logger with default options
import logger from 'redux-logger'
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
)

// Note passing middleware as the third argument requires redux@>=3.1.0
```

I added that into my code and it tells me

```
'reducer' is not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you didnt define reducer anywhere so its not defined

Comment: @ChrisLi Still relatively new to Redux and React, but basically, what you're saying is that we're supposed to manually define the reducer? Not import it from somewhere? Because, as mentioned, it wasnt stated anywhere on where the reducre came from and the tutorial videos I saw all had it by itself and working.

Comment: You also have no import statement there.

Comment: Generally though, since you are just learning Redux, as a FYI: you are learning a very outdated style of Redux here. Modern Redux does not use `createStore`, switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPE strings, immutable reducer logic, hand-written action creators or connect. It's 1/4 of the code. Please follow the **official** Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts to learn the official up-to-date recommendations.

Comment: @phry As mentioned, ```createStore``` is literally what the tutorial in the ```Redux-Logger``` is teaching to do; its most basic implementation.

Comment: @Erik and I am telling you that no matter what an external tutorial says, we as the Redux team do not want you to use `createStore` in a modern application. We cannot change outdated external documentation. Redux-logger is a middleware that can be set up like any other middleware - there is nothing specific about it. If you ever need to set up a middleware, that is documented [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#intended-usage). But generally you probably don't need Redux-Logger since RTK autmatically sets up the Redux Devtools which are much more powerfull.

Comment: And as I said, the error itself here is that you did not import `reducer` into this file, so there is no variable `reducer` that is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone in the future stumbles about this: the documentation of redux-logger shows an outdated example using an outdated style of Redux.

In modern Redux, you would be using `configureStore` instead, as shown [by this example from the Redux-Toolkit documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#intended-usage):

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import logger from 'redux-logger'

import rootReducer from './reducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
})
```